# How to modify G-code or a better place to get it

Tags: g-code

I have built a 3D printer from salvaged/purchased parts. I am using an Arduino Uno and three easy driver stepper drivers with 3 CD-ROMs drives and a PC power unit. I ordered a 3D pen and have it mounted with a transistor to switch it on/off. Everything works but when I try to run code that I got from makercam.com it seems like it wants to fill in the shape rather than build up.

I followed this tutorial [YouTube - How To Make A Cheap 3D Printer](https://youtu.be/anIy6eb1fW0) and after modifying the G-code I am unable to get any successful prints.

[image: Bad prints]

Comment: The makercam.com domain appears not to exist any longer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download an stl file from Thingiverse.com

Put your .stl file in a slicer program like cura

It will output gcode for 3d objects rather than 2d.

Answer (score 2):

I would typically shy away from downloading gcode and printing it directly.  Always slice it yourself since, inevitably, every printer is different.  What happens if the gcode is setup for ABS (higher temps) and you are printing with PLA?  If it's setup for a build platform larger than yours and you just hit endstops?

Definitely go with Aaron's idea, download a model (Thingiverse is great, but there are SO many sites where you can get files), configure a slicer for your print settings (I prefer slic3r to Cura, but both are great), slice it and print away.

Comment: This is pretty much what Aaron said. But after slicing there is no way to just print because my printer is based from grbl which is a milling software and i dont have a proper extruder. So the best way i have found is to open the sliced file in notepad and make adjustments to feedrates and layer heights manually.

Comment: If you're adjusting feedrates, then you have an extruder.  If you have an extruder, any slicer can use whatever rates you give it.  If you can change it manually, you can have it set properly in slic3r or Cura or Simplify3D - unless we're not understanding one another.  Same with layer heights.  You can set your layer heights based on whatever Z-axis values you have on your steppers.  grbl just reads gcode, same as Marlin or any others.  I'm confused as to what the issue is here.

Comment: I can adjust on slic3r but i was more wanting to learn how to control my machine with gcode. G1 X5 Y5 E.5 F300 doesnt regster with grbl bc its a milling software. M3 and M5 turn the spindle on and off and thats what I'm using to activate the extruder on my 3d pen So basically i have to delete the E values and manually enter start and stop commands The variable resistor on the side of the 3d pen cant be easily adjusted while its moving. But I've got it all figured out now. I can open a txt editor and write a file that prints successfully and it has been a great learning exp. Buying anet A8 next

Comment: Hmmm, good stuff!